# error inser DB doctrine symfony php

Tags: php, entity-framework, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have this error:

> A new entity was found through the relationship
>   'AppBundle\Entity\LikeSubject#subject' that was not configured to
>   cascade persist operations for entity:
>   AppBundle\Entity\Subject@0000000049bfd0d6000000010ab8141e. To solve
>   this issue: Either explicitly call EntityManager#persist() on this
>   unknown entity or configure cascade persist this association in the
>   mapping for example @ManyToOne(..,cascade={"persist"}). If you cannot
>   find out which entity causes the problem implement
>   'AppBundle\Entity\Subject#__toString()' to get a clue.

When I try to persist an entity.
this is the code to persist:

```
public function create( $entity ) {
    $this->entityManager->getConnection()->beginTransaction();
    try {
        $this->entityManager->persist($entity);
        $this->entityManager->flush();
        $this->entityManager->getConnection()->commit();
        return true;
    } catch ( Exception $e ) {
        $this->entityManager->getConnection()->rollBack();
        return false;
    }
}
```

and this is the table:

```
CREATE TABLE like_subject (
    id INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    user_platform VARCHAR(20),
    subject VARCHAR(20),
    FOREIGN KEY ( subject ) REFERENCES subject ( name ),
    FOREIGN KEY ( user_platform ) REFERENCES user_platform ( username )
)
ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
CREATE INDEX index_like_subject ON like_subject ( user_platform );
```

entity code:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * LikeSubject
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="like_subject", indexes={@ORM\Index(name="subject", columns={"subject"}), @ORM\Index(name="index_like_subject", columns={"user_platform"})})
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class LikeSubject
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var \AppBundle\Entity\Subject
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Subject", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="subject", referencedColumnName="name")
     * })
     */
    private $subject;

    /**
     * @var \AppBundle\Entity\UserPlatform
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\UserPlatform", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_platform", referencedColumnName="username")
     * })
     */
    private $userPlatform;



    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set subject
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Subject $subject
     *
     * @return LikeSubject
     */
    public function setSubject(\AppBundle\Entity\Subject $subject = null)
    {
        $this->subject = $subject;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get subject
     *
     * @return \AppBundle\Entity\Subject
     */
    public function getSubject()
    {
        return $this->subject;
    }

    /**
     * Set userPlatform
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\UserPlatform $userPlatform
     *
     * @return LikeSubject
     */
    public function setUserPlatform(\AppBundle\Entity\UserPlatform $userPlatform = null)
    {
        $this->userPlatform = $userPlatform;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get userPlatform
     *
     * @return \AppBundle\Entity\UserPlatform
     */
    public function getUserPlatform()
    {
        return $this->userPlatform;
    }
}
```

And I call the method so:

```
class testController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/lucky/number")
     */
    public function numberAction()
    {
        $user = new UserPlatform();
        $user->setAbilitationCode("");
        $user->setUsername("francoscala");
        $user->setAdsDisabled(true);
        $user->setBirthDate(new \DateTime("now"));
        $user->setCredits(12);
        $user->setEmail("asdasd@asdasd.ir");
        $user->setEnabled(true);
        $user->setFirstName("francesco");
        $user->setGender("male");
        $user->setLastName("scala");
        $user->setPassword("pass");
        $user->setProfileImage("null");
        $user->setRegistrationDate(new \DateTime("now"));



        $likeSubjectPF = $this->get('facade.LikeSubjectFacade');



        $subject = new Subject();
        $subject->setName("COMPUTER");
        //$res = $subjectPF->create($subject);

        $like = new \AppBundle\Entity\LikeSubject();
        $like->setUserPlatform($user);
        $like->setSubject($subject);


        $likeSubjectPF->create($like);


        }

    }
```

What is the problem, what I have to do?
Thanks

Comment: Could you add `AppBundle\Entity\LikeSubject` entity? The problem is probably up there

Comment: yes sure, now i load the code

Comment: What object do you pass to `public function create( $entity )`? Is it `public function create(LikeSubject $entity)` or something else?

Comment: I have loaded the code that I use to call the function create